# Django transactions don't work

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions

I have two computers. One with windows 7, python 2.7.6, django 1.6.0, and mysql ver 14.14 distrib 5.6.20.

The other one is linux with python 2.7.3, django 1.6.0, and mysql ver 14.14 distrib 5.1.66.

I have exactly the same script on these machines, the script includes `@transaction.atomic` around a function. The function saves some data to the DB and then raises a custom exception.

The transaction should not be committed.

It works perfectly on the first machine, and doesn't work on the second one (the transaction is committed).

Any ideas? Pleeaasseee I'm really running out of ideas!!

Comment: What storage engine are you using in MySQL? Are you sure you are using the same one on both machines?

Comment: Wow you are right! That was it! MyIASM doesn't work but InnoDB does!